# Vite erroring when using local paths for dependency in package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

My package.json contains a dependency in a local path

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "~shared": "file:../shared",
  }
}
```

This is a directory that contains a bunch of React components, utils, and styles that are shared between a few different frontend projects.

I'm using Vite to bundle this frontend, but it doesn't seem to be able to take into account the local path and I receive the following error

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "~shared/components/button" from "/web/path-to-a-file.tsx".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime
```

I've tried using `resolve.alias` in Vite's config to replicate this, but that gets rid of any dependency resolution which is the advantage of using npm local path dependencies (the file `/shared/components/button` is importing the React from `/shared/node_modules` that I need to be there for development, while `/web/path-to-a-file.tsx` is importing its own React) and breaks everything more.

I know there are some npm wrappers (i.e. yarn workspaces, lerna) that have better solutions for this but I want to be able to get this working without introducing layers on top of npm

My other option is to symlink the shared folder into each frontend package

Comment: Try to set `resolve: { alias: { ... } }` in vite config